# Can sitemap.xml precessors cope with <!ENTITY name "my text">?

Tags: sitemap

Can sitemap.xml precessors cope with this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY  port ":8080">
<!ENTITY  host"http://example.com&port;">
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
    <loc>&host;/path/</loc>
 <!-- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume so. It will most likely just ignore it though. If there is no Sitemaps DTD, I think it has to ignore it unless it expects it.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference):

> In the markup languages SGML, HTML, XHTML and XML, a character entity reference is a reference to a particular kind of named entity that has been predefined or explicitly declared in a Document Type Definition (DTD). The "replacement text" of the entity consists of a **single character** from the Universal Character Set/Unicode. The purpose of a character entity reference is to provide a way to refer to a character that is not universally encodable.

In short, no. Not unless the preprocessor is very forgiving.